# On Accessing DbContext , I get System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am writing this code :

```
var pOrders =   await _dbContext.POrders.Where(x => x.ShipId == data.shipNumber).ToListAsync();
                pOrders.ForEach(async po =>
                {
                    var cardProcess =  await _dbContext.CardProcesses.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => po.Id == x.PurchaseOrderId);
                    cardProcess.SettleStatus = ViewModels.SettleStatus.NA.ToString();
              
                    var shipId = po.ShipId;
                    var taskFile = await _dbContext.TaskFiles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ShipNumber == shipId);
                    var taskFileId = taskFile.Id;
                    var taskFilesExt = await _dbContext.TaskFileExts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.TaskFileId == taskFileId);
                    if (taskFilesExt != null)
                    {
                        taskFilesExt.SettlStatus = NA.ToString();

                        taskFilesExt.SettleStatus_NA +=  1 ;

                        jtaskFilesExt.SettleStatus_NA -= model.OldStatus.ToString() == NA.ToString() ? 1 : 0;
                        taskFilesExt.SettleStatus_Audited -= model.OldStatus.ToString() == Audited.ToString() ? 1 : 0;
                        taskFilesExt.SettlStatus_ReadyToPay -= model.OldStatus.ToString() == ReadyToPay.ToString() ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                });
```

But I am getting this error when I try to access dbContext in the 4th line:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application
```

I have been trying to correct this with no success. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Difficult to tell without a complete example. Many `ForEach` extension methods (we don't know what you're using) don't deal well with async lambdas and those that do I would expect to return something `await`able - so either you're just missing an `await` which the compiler should be flagging or you shouldn't be using that `ForEach` method.

Comment: Where does `_dbContext` come from? The error message explains one possible reason for this error. The rest of the code has problems too - instead of using EF Core to load the relevant orders and all the related `CardProcess`, `TaskFiles` etc in a single operation, this is loading them one by one, using a separate connection and query each time. This is the slowest way possible of loading data. This is called `RBAR` - Row-By-Agonizing-Row

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using dependency Injection for dbcontext

Comment: @sapter where do you use it? You wouldn't get such an error in a controller action, because DI creates a new instance for each request. You'd get that error if you stored the DbContext in a static field and tried to reuse it. You'd also get that error if you tried to use a scoped DbContext in a BackgroundService

Comment: You cannot use `ForEach` with async lambda. Use `foreach` instead.

Comment: As for the error itself, I suspect it's because *the tasks are never awaited* and the RBAR code is so slow that the DbContext gets disposed before `ForEach` completes. `List.ForEach` in this case fires off N tasks *that nobody awaits*. The action will return right after that and the DbContext will get disposed. The code will crash before even the first `_dbContext.CardProcesses.FirstOrDefaultAsync` call completes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I resolved the error by removing await from inside every dbContext call inside the foreach loop. This is weird . I though we are suppposed to await every call.

Comment: No, that didn't fix anything. You no longer see the exceptions. It's not `await` that causes the problem, it's the *lack* of `await` on the 100-1000 tasks started by `ForEach`

Comment: None of the changes inside `ForEach` is saved to the database or visible outside it. `taskFile` and `taskFileExt` are thrown away after every iteration. What is this code supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `List.ForEach` it is not designed for asynchronous execution. Instead of initializing objects it creates tasks which are executed in background. Which cause that context is disposed before all tasks are finished.

Just replace with `foreach`

```cs
var pOrders = await _dbContext.POrders.Where(x => x.ShipId == data.shipNumber).ToListAsync();

foreach (var po in pOrders)
{
    var cardProcess =  await _dbContext.CardProcesses.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => po.Id == x.PurchaseOrderId);
    ....
};
```

Comment: When I use forEach it says List<> does not contain a definition for 'forEach'....
I resolved the error by removing await in front of dbContext call inside the loop..

Comment: How it can be? [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement) is standard C# statement for `IEnumerable`. You have resolved it wrong.